# Keeping the first day of the month in a timestamp object

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I have a DataFrame with a timestamp column containing all the days of the year.

I would like to keep only the first day of the month, any idea of how should I do this?

Comment: you can use the [`dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) "day" to select elements/rows where the `day` attribute is 1. please add a [mre] if you need more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

With that in mind, you can access the day attribute of a datetime object as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.today()
dt.day
```

Output:

```
2021-07-11 09:37:23.122548
11
```

You could then use masking to select rows in your dataframe that have a value of 1 for day as below:

```
df = df[df['date_column'].dt.day == 1]
```

You'll just need to replace 'date_column' with whatever your date column is called.